# Django - Uploading image through custom models in admin not working

Tags: django, django-models, frameworks

I'm currently working on a Django project, and for this I need to add a way of inputting images to each custom page through the admin panel. However, when I attempt to add this functionality and fill in the form on the admin page, I get shown this:

[image: What I see when I attempt to fill in the form]

This is what my models.py looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Bird(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(help_text='Upload Image')
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter Breed')
    breed_sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter Breed Subtype')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, help_text='Enter Description')
    price = models.FloatField(help_text='Enter Price Here')
    age_in_years = models.IntegerField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter Age in Years')
    age_in_months = models.IntegerField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter Age in Months')
    tame = models.BooleanField(help_text='Is the bird tame?')
    
    
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('model-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.image
        return self.breed
        return self.price
        return self.age_in_years
        return self.age_in_months
        return self.breed_sub_category
        return self.tame
        return self.description
```

And this is what my admin.py looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Bird

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Bird)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, you have got multiple return statements. Just use one. You also cant use

```
return self.image
```

because its not a string but an image object.

To solve your problem remove the `__str__` method.  Let django handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change yout `__str__` method to this.

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
        return self.breed
        return int(self.price)
        return int(self.age_in_years)
        return int(self.age_in_months)
        return self.breed_sub_category
        return bool(self.tame)
        return self.description
```